# Export daily image from PROBA-V

Tags: google-earth-engine, export

I'm trying to download single NDVI image from Proba-V. Proba-V produces images every 2 days. [Here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/VITO_PROBAV_C1_S1_TOC_100M) is the link of the product. When I try to export a single image, I am getting this error:

```
Line 28: subtracted.reproject is not a function
```

Why is that? A [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/93f8038dd0fcc25c9d1ddc1ecd763359) to the code and the code:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-02-02', '2018-02-03'))
                  .select('NDVI')
                  .filterBounds(table);

var subtracted = dataset.map(function (image) {
  return image.subtract(20).divide(250)
});

// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);
var image_mollweide = subtracted.reproject({
  crs: proj_mollweide,
  scale: 100
});

Export.image.toDrive({
image: image_mollweide,
description: 'ndvi',
scale: 100, //100 for Band10
maxPixels: 1000000000000,
region: table,
folder: 'Landsat-5'});
```

And the [shapefile](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/nikostziokas/bangkok_54009) I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem appears because you are trying to apply 'reproject' **ee.Image** method to an **Image Collection**. It would be recommended that this method is included within the function **subtracted** as follows:

```
// Project the image to Mollweide.
var wkt = ' \
  PROJCS["World_Mollweide", \
    GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984", \
      DATUM["WGS_1984", \
        SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137,298.257223563]], \
      PRIMEM["Greenwich",0], \
      UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]], \
    PROJECTION["Mollweide"], \
    PARAMETER["False_Easting",0], \
    PARAMETER["False_Northing",0], \
    PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",0], \
    UNIT["Meter",1], \
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","54009"]]';

var proj_mollweide = ee.Projection(wkt);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('VITO/PROBAV/C1/S1_TOC_100M')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-02-03', '2018-02-04')) 
                  .select('NDVI')
                  .filterBounds(table);

var subtracted = dataset.map(function (image) {
  return image.subtract(20)
              .divide(250)
              .reproject({crs: proj_mollweide, scale: 100})
              .clip(table);
});
```

After running [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/ca0d16a4b6a0e3174b664fa36f8ca6b6) for a geometry near to Bangkok (your shapefile is not available), I got following result for the first element of **image_mollweide** Image Collection. That image was also exported and visualized satisfactorily in QGIS with ESRI:54009 World_Mollweide projection.

[image]